# How to use instanceof type parameter in java?

Tags: java, android, parameters, type-conversion

I want to use this code in Java:

```
public <T extends View> T getView(int resId){
    final View v = findViewById(resId);
    if(v instanceof T) return (T)findViewById(resId);
    return null;
}
```

But the statement **v instanceof T** failed to compile, the error message is "Class or Array expect". So how I can achieve the type checking in this case?

Some users say because of type erasure in Java, Java do not know what T is, but if Java do not know what T is, how it achieve the class cast statement such as **(T)findViewById(resId)**?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
public <T> T getView(int resId){
    final View v = findViewById(resId);
    if(v instanceof View)
        return (T)findViewById(resId);
    return null;
}
```

Comment: hi...but v is a instance of View already. why should i check it again? i mean   you already declare the type of v is View.